# Power BI -- return data based on previous column value in query editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have encountered this issue

[image]

1. If the value in the second column is "Agree" or "Strongly Agree", the corresponding cell in the third column should be empty (null).
2. If the value in the second column is "Disagree" or "Strongly Disagree", the corresponding cell in the third column should display the value from the next row of the second column.

Can someone kindly take a look and help me solve this? Thanks!!

I have tried using two index columns to merge (the first index column starts from 0, the second index column starts from 1), but this doesn't work

---

The new issue arises when I added the "Add Shifted Answer" step

[image]

Previous step works fine..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what you wanted returned in the third column if the second column contained neither Agree nor Disagree.  I returned a null, but you can easily change that.

The algorithm consistis of adding a "shifted" column so that we are using a replacement on the same row, instead of using an Index column.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table28"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Question Category", type text}, {"Answer Category", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Answer Category", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Add Shifted Answer" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Trimmed Text") &
         {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Trimmed Text"[Answer Category],1) & {null}},
         type table[Question Category=text, Answer Category=text, Shifted Answer=text]),

//Note use of Text.Lower as M-Code is case sensitive
    #"Add Result" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Shifted Answer", "Result", each if Text.Lower([Answer Category])="agree" or Text.Lower([Answer Category])="strongly agree"
            then null 
            else if Text.Lower([Answer Category])="disagree" or Text.Lower([Answer Category])="strongly disagree"
            then [Shifted Answer] else null, type nullable text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Result",{"Shifted Answer"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Original Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for getting back this quick.. but I have met the new issue after adding the "Add shifted answer" step (I have attached the screenshot in my question above)... May I know why this happen? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The second column will only have these 4 options: Agree/Strongly Agree/Disagree/Strongly Disagree....   thanks!

Comment: @kkk It happened because you still have the `Answer Category - Copy` column in your preceding step; and you don't name it in the table type record. Seeing no purpose for that copy, I do not show it in my data table.

Comment: @kkk You write `The second column will only have these 4 options: Agre...` but there are also various answers in the second column. What do you want in the third column if there is an answer in the 2nd column. I showed a null.